# Why does compiler not give a warning in this case

Tags: c, memcpy

This piece of code :

```
       char buff[255];
       memcpy(buff,0,255);
```

The compiler doesn't give any warning during compilation but the process fails with a segmentation fault
But when I compile the following code

```
       char buff[255];
       memcpy(buff,2,255);
```

The compiler gives the following warning

> warning: passing argument 2 of 'memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Why does compiler not give an warning for the constant 0
I am using GCC version 4.7.2

Also is there some compiler flag that will give warnings for such code

Comment: what are your intentions with that code? because it almost seems like you are trying to do a `memset(buff,0,255)` or `memset(buff,2,255)`

Comment: Aye that was the intention of the person who wrote this piece of code.surprisingly the code did not fail for 2 years and failed on me . so I was trying to reproduce a case where I dont get a seg fault for memcpy( unsuccessfully) . That led to the question that I posted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`0` is implicitly converted to the null pointer when used in a pointer context.  `2` isn't implicitly converted to a pointer type, hence the warning.

You can read more at the [`comp.lang.c` FAQ, section 5](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html), specifically [Question 5.2](http://c-faq.com/null/null2.html).

In a quick test here, neither GCC nor Clang warned about the `0` case (without extra flags), but the [clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/index.html) does:

```
example.c:6:4: warning: Null pointer argument in call to memory copy function
   memcpy(buff,0,255);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:55:6: note: expanded from macro 'memcpy'
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))     \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

As has been mentioned elsewhere in comments here, GCC will warn if you pass `-Wnonnull` (also included with `-Wall`):

```
$ gcc -Wnonnull example.c -o example
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:6: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

`2` is not a pointer; thus you get a warning.

`0` is the null pointer, so the compiler doesn't see anything wrong with that code.

Within the context of `memcpy()`, passing the null pointer doesn't make sense, but the compiler doesn't have a warning for every possible non-sensical function call.
Especially in C, you are expected to write code that makes sense.

Comment: Actually GCC emits one if you enable `-Wnonnull`

Answer (score 1):

Because `0` in a pointer context is a *null pointer constant*, while 2 is an integer of type `int`, even in a pointer context.